# Setting a Static IP from Boot Drive (headless static IP)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, static-ip

I'm putting multiple RPIs onto a subnet together connected via ethernet (all of them headless) using a switch and I want to be able to know what their IPs are when I first boot them. They won't be connected to a router or anything so they won't be assigned an IP.

Ideally I want to be able to edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf from the boot drive on the SD cards directly before booting the Pis for the first time. Alternatively, is there another way to set a static IP address from the boot drive?

Comment: You are putting multiple RPIs onto a subnet together connected via ethernet. So you have at least a switch, right?

Comment: @Ingo yes, I'm using a switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I advise against static IP addresses, but an isolated network is one of the few valid use cases.

You can connect to the Pi over a direct Ethernet link to the Pi (not via a switch or router) using the [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address), although discovering this can be problematic.

You can easily connect from Linux and OS X with `ssh pi@hostname.local` (the default hostname is raspberrypi) This should work with popular GUI ssh programs. This is sometimes problematic with some versions of Windows and networks which use .local in a non-standard way. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local)

The other alternative is to assign an IP by including something like `ip=192.168.0.10` in `cmdline.txt`. See https://elinux.org/RPi_cmdline.txt

I have not used the last in a modern Raspbian using `dhcpcd`, but it should still work, and should be replaced by a normal configuration.

PS accessing `ext4` partitions from `macOS` is difficult, since the introduction of SIP. There may be 3rd party (paid) solutions which work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding `ip=192.168.3.21` to the end of `cmdline.txt` from the boot partition on the SD card directly and it didn't seem to take affect. Is there another step I am missing?

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately I can provide no other ideas. I haven't used this for over 4 years (when Raspbian used Debian networking) - now I use `raspberrypi.local` if I need direct connection. You should provide more detail of EXACTLY your configuration. NOTE `ssh` is NOT enabled by default, and needs `ssh` on the boot partition.

Comment: I just tested the ip=... option in cmdline.txt with latest raspios release, it works correctly

Comment: @Matt try the following `ip=192.168.3.21::192.168.3.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off` where `192.168.3.1` is your gateway and `255.255.255.0` is network mask. It worked for me with a fresh rasp pi 64 bit image - no keyboard and monitor

Answer (score 4):

SD card for raspibian OS has two partitions /boot and /rootfs. Using SD card reader, I mounted the partitions onto my system with ubuntu OS.
For setting up static IP address edit the file **dhcpcd.conf** with root privileges.

```
  $ sudo nano ~/rootfs/etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Add the static IP details in the file.

```
   interface eth0    
   static ip_address = 10.0.0.100
```

Save (Ctrl+x, Press y).

Since I was using headless setup ethernet cable connection between RPi and my laptop, I needed ssh to be enabled as default. To enable ssh, create an empty file named ssh in the /boot partition

```
   $ cd /boot
   $ touch ssh
```

Unmount partitions.
Plug the SD card back to the raspberry pi board. Now the device (with username "pi", here) is accessible through ssh from the system.

```
$ sudo ssh pi@10.0.0.100`
```

(My system was set with static IP of 10.0.0.200)

I found this example of how to do headless IP address setup for raspibian on raspberry pi with ubuntu in the following link. https://foolsvilla.blogspot.com/2020/03/how-to-set-static-ip-address-for.html . It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

We should be clear on terminology. When you say `boot drive`, are you referring to the SD card? That's fine, but know that there is a `/boot` partition on the SD card also (a *FAT filesystem), and it has a role in configuring some aspects of RPi when it is first booted. Unfortunately, setting static IP addresses can't be done in the `/boot` folder. However: [If you have an RPi 4, you can configure the bootloader skip the DHCP process entirely, and assign a static IP address](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#static-ip-address-configuration).

To edit the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file, you'll need to mount the root partition (`/`) of the `boot drive` (the SD card) using a system that can read the `ext4` filesystem (e.g. you could remove it from your RPi, and mount it using an Ubuntu laptop). Another way would be to boot your RPi using a "live linux" thumb drive (Debian or Linux), and edit the file in situ.

Comment: yes I meant the SD card. Do you know if there is any way to read the ext4 filesystem from Mac?

Comment: I wouldn't try it on *my* Mac ([REF](https://hackmylinux.com/2018/02/18/how-to-mount-and-read-a-linux-partition-on-a-mac-ext2-ext3-ext4/)), but there are some commercial tools that claim to do this ([example](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/#)), and here's a [github page with some info.](https://github.com/frallain/wiki/wiki/Reading-ext4-partitions-from-Windows--or-MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution to changing files on the `ext4` SD-card, as it was suggested by Seamus:

1. First you should connect your Raspberry Pi with another computer via Ethernet cable.
2. After connecting your Raspberry Pi with another device (without a running DHCP server) via ethernet cable, on a new Raspbian installation your Raspberry Pi will have a self assigned link-local IP-address in the range of `169.254.1.0` to `169.254.254.255`.
3. Now the Ethernet interface on your computer also needs an IP address in the same subnet as the Raspberry Pi. If it did not self assign a link-local IP-address, you should set it yourself by choosing any in the range of `169.254.1.0` to `169.254.254.255`.
   On Linux, e.g. use `sudo ifconfig eth0 169.254.100.100`
4. Now you can directly `ssh` into your Raspberry Pi by

   `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`

   and change the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file remotely.

If the `raspberrypi.local` addressing does not work, you need to search for the IP-address of your Raspberry Pi with a network scanner. On a Linux machine you can e.g. use `arp-scan`:

```
sudo arp-scan –interface=eth0 169.254.0.0/16
```

After finding the IP-address, you can now `ssh` into your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to move the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file to the boot partition and then symlinking to it from the `/etc` directory by issuing

```
# mv /etc/dhcpcd.conf /boot/dhcpcd.conf
# ln -s /boot/dhcpcd.conf /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

Then you have the config file laying around in the boot partition and can access it from e.g. a Windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full headless setup of a static IP, you can update `cmdline.txt` in `boot` volume by adding the following string:
`ip=192.168.0.5::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off` where

- `192.168.0.5` your PI's static IP
- `192.168.0.1` your gateway (is a pretty much default value for all home networks)
- `255.255.255.0` your netmask (is a pretty much default value for all home networks)

This worked for my completely headless setup (no monitor, no keyboard connected to PI) in `Linux raspberrypi 5.10.92-v8+ #1514 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 17 17:39:38 GMT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Make sure your static IP address is not being used or is not in the DHCP address space (usually `192.168.0.100`-`192.168.0.200`)

My config `cmdline.txt`:

`console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=cb15ae4d-02 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh ip=192.168.0.5::192.168.0.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off`

Note: make sure you have one space between previous command and `pi=..`